# the genitive of 'one' (used instead of 'you') in formal contexts

Tags: grammar, writing, saxon-genitive

It's better to use 'one' instead of 'you' in formal writing but what about the genitive of 'one'?

your body => one's body/ ones body / ...?

What is correct?

Comment: "One's body" is correct.

Comment: Related: [Academic writing: “one's”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151664), 
[Is the possessive of “one” spelled “ones” or “one's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26327), https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you would use the possessive form of *you* (*your*), you would similarly use the possessive form of *one*:  ***one's***.

More info from [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/one-and-one-s) and [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/possessive-ones-or-ones.1017/).